# loading file without whole path visual studios 2012

Tags: visual-c++, wic

I am writing a program in **Visual Studio 2012**. I am using Windows Imaging component I want to put image files for my program to use without them being resources. I want to make them download with the program when someone downloads it.

So my problem is if I specify the direct path in the program say:

```
C:\Users\Billy\Documents\Background.
```

How would I do that without having to specify `Users\Billy\Documents`. Since it will be different on others computers.

Answer (score 0):

Call SHGetFolderPath to get any of the user-dependent path names. Then concatenate the file name to the retrieved path.

Comment: Could I get a quick example

Comment: Never mind cant use SHGetFolderPath it says not to use it on msdn that its supported only for backwards compatibility it is replaced with SHGetKnowFolderPath, and im trying to target windows vista and up.

Comment: Ok oddly enough I cant find SHGetKnownFolderPath in my program even though I have shell32.dll,  Shlobj.h, shell32.lib, and KnownFolders.h in my program